# How do I check JsonObject have nothing android like below format

Tags: android, json

```
{
    "error": false,
    "company_data": [
        {
            "company": {
                "details": [
                    {}
                ],
                "product": [
                    {}
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonString);
if(object.has("error"))
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(output);

JsonArray array  = jsonObject.getJsonArray("company_data");

if(array.length()!=0)
{
  for(int i =0;i<array.length;i++)
    {
     JSONObject company = array.getJSONObject("company");

     JSONArray detailArray = company.getJsonArray("details");

       if(detailArray,length()!0)

           {

                //do Something

           }
        else
           {

           //array Empty

            }
      }

}
```